# After freeing variable, can we use it?

Tags: c

`free(variable);`, then I really need to use `variable's` value once more. Will it work? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: Have you considered not `free`ing it until your done with it?

Comment: Don't let go of something until you're *really* ready to let it go...

Comment: If you _really_ need it, it won't work. If you **really really** need it, then it might work.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_You_Wish_upon_a_Star

Comment: @Bye Please read this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/426894

Comment: "Location : Php world" pretty much explains everything about this question.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: I dunno.  In PHP, once you lose your references to stuff, it's pretty much *gone*.  He wouldn't have gotten these harebrained ideas about ghost values from there.  This sounds more like wishful thinking.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Will it work?

IDK. It's undefined behavior, so it might or might not work.

> Is it a bad practice?

Yes.

Comment: I really really need to use it...

Comment: @bye then just **don't friggin' free it...**

Comment: @bye you need to redesign your application so that you don't need it after freeing it.

Answer (score 7):

It will work just fine!

```
int *f = malloc( 128 );
free( f );
printf( "F has the value: %p\n", f );
```

Now, if you want the value that was in `*f`, that's another question.

Comment: This is the least helpful technically correct answer ever!

Comment: @PeteFordham http://theinfosphere.org/images/thumb/9/9f/Number_1.0.png/180px-Number_1.0.png

Comment: Please.. for the sake of all those who fail to understand how pointers and memory management work... add a big fat warning to this answer. I don't want anyone using it as a reference on why what he's doing is acceptable.

Comment: How is this technically correct? o.O Using a pointer in any way after freeing it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @H2CO3: *Dereferencing* such a pointer in any way is UB.  Printing it, though?  Its pointee has been freed, but the pointer itself still has a value -- that value just isn't useful anymore.

Comment: @cHao Logically and actually it is the case, of course, but the C standard says that using it in **any way** (including getting the address, even without dereferencing it, and performing pointer arithmetic) is undefined.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, but does not fall under 'not an answer'. Please hold your flags folks.

Answer (score 4):

See [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) for free():

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr,

That means when you call `malloc()` you own the memory that it's pointing to, you know exactly what is there, once you call:

```
free(variable);
```

It is no longer owned by you. All bets are off. There is *no good reason* to access memory once it's been freed. If you really need it, you can not free it. If you must free it, make a copy of the data (if that's what you need)

Answer (score 3):

The *variable* is still available for use; *the heap memory that it pointed to* is not.

IOW, this is perfectly reasonable (if contrived):

```
int *variable = malloc(sizeof *variable);
*variable = 1;
printf("%p: %d", (void *) variable, *variable);
free(variable);
variable = malloc(sizeof *variable);
*variable = 2;
printf("%p: %d", (void *) variable, *variable);
```

After calling `free`, I can assign a *new* pointer value to `variable` and continue to work with it.  In that sense, I can continue to use `variable`.

This, however, will *not* work (or at least, its behavior is *undefined*):

```
int *variable = malloc(sizeof *variable);
*variable = 1;
free(variable);
*variable = 2;
```

After calling `free`, the memory that `variable` *used* to point to may not be available anymore.  Attempting to write to it could lead to a crash, or corrupt memory you're using elsewhere, or it could *appear* to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Once freed, you should not reuse the variable. If you need it again, move your freeing of the variable until after you will ever need it.

Freeing a variable deallocates its memory. While the location that variable was at may still hold the old value, it may not. It is bad practice to use a variable that has been freed, and often leads to bugs and crashes.

Comment: Bonus fun: On linux, `free` may actually [unmap](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) the memory area so accessing it afterwards causes a segfault, not just (possibly corrupted) data.